# I am trying to store name of ordered meals for each user in order table, I am using Larvel

Tags: laravel-5

this is the order table

```
 $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('phone_number');    
        $table->string('meal_name');
        $table->Integer('quantity');
```

and this is the meal_user table which contains the order informations before confirming it by the user

```
  $table->double('quantity');
        $table->text('note')->nullble();
        $table->string('meal_size');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone_number')->nullable(); 
        $table->bigInteger('location_id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('meal_id');
```

what I am trying to do is when the user confirm his orders it stores in the order table, but for each user has one record with all ordered meal names